# Java: How do I have my program determine if a number has went up a certain amount and if so do a particular equation?

Tags: java

I have to create a shipping charge program and there is tax involved. Here are the conditions I need to satisfy:

```
1) Weight <= 1kg, tax per 1000 miles = 1.70
2) 1kg < Weight <= 5kg, tax per 1000 miles = 2.20
3) 5kg < Weight <= 10kg, tax per 1000 miles = 6.70
4) Weight > 10kg, tax per 1000 miles = 9.80
```

If the weight is 1kg or below and is shipping 1-1000 miles, then the tax is 1.70. Well I have that part down and coded, the issue is that the tax will charge for every 1000 miles traveled. So, I was wondering how I would go about writing out code to tell java to double the tax every time a 1000 miles has been reached. So if a user inputs 2,000 miles, I want the program to output 3.40 as the tax. I thought about switch and if statements, but that just seemed extensive and I'm sure there's an easier way.

Also, if someone would take a look at my code below, my first calculation outputs the correct answer, tax, the rest only output 0.0?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;
public class MyShippingCharges3{
private static double WeightOfPackage;
private static int MilesShipped;
private static double tax = 1.7;
private static double tax1 = 2.2;
private static double tax2 = 6.7;
private static double tax3 = 9.8;
private static double result;
   public static void main(String [] args){
      readData();
      calculations();
      printOutput();
      displayTable();
   }

   public static void readData(){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter weight of package in KG: ");
      WeightOfPackage = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter how many miles the package will travel: ");
      MilesShipped = sc.nextInt();
   }

   public static void calculations(){
      if (WeightOfPackage <= 1){
         if (MilesShipped <= 1000){
           result = tax;
           }
      else if (WeightOfPackage > 1 && WeightOfPackage <= 5){
         if (MilesShipped <= 1000){
            result = tax1;
            }
            }
     else if (WeightOfPackage > 5 && WeightOfPackage <= 10){
         if (MilesShipped <= 1000) {
            result = tax2;
            }
            }
     else if (WeightOfPackage > 10){
         if(MilesShipped <= 1000){
            result = tax3;
            }
            }

   }

   }

   public static void printOutput(){
      System.out.print("Your cost is: " + result+"0");

   }

   public static void displayTable(){


   }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a simple formula: `tax = miles / 1000 * 1.7`

Comment: divide by `1000` and mutiple this value by the tax

Comment: ...I completely overlooked that! I've been trying to think of a long drawn out complicated code, thanks! I swear I'm not dumb!

Comment: I updated the code, however, now it's outputting 0.0, like the issue above? I said: tax = (MilesShipped / 1000) * 1.7;
           result = tax;

Comment: What are you outputting? `tax` was just an example. Use whatever variable you need. E.g., `result = MilesShipped / 1000 * tax;`.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the same output in the output method: System.out.print("Your tax is: " + result); I have a private static double tax; to store the answer.

Comment: Your first if condition _if (WeightOfPackage <= 1){_ is weird, you have not closed that IF condition properly, so it does not enter the rest of the code, when weight is greater than 1 KG. Also, what is the criteria for tax? I mean if 1000 miles then tax1, 2000 miles then tax2? Is your tax value only dependent on miles or the weight too?

Comment: The criteria is 1kg or less is: 1.7, 2kg - 5kg is: 2.2, 6 - 10kg: 6.7, and anything over 10kg is: 9.8. Then, depending on how many miles is traveled will determine the tax. So, for instance, if the weight is 1kg and has traveled 2000 miles, the answer will be 3.4. I'll take a look and close it properly.

Comment: Your result was coming as 0.0 in case your input didn't satisfy any of the IF condition, hence output was default double value 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;

public class Tax {

    private static double WeightOfPackage;
    private static int MilesShipped;
    private static double tax = 1.7;
    private static double tax1 = 2.2;
    private static double tax2 = 6.7;
    private static double tax3 = 9.8;
    private static double result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readData();
        calculations();
        printOutput();
        displayTable();
    }

    public static void readData() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter weight of package in KG: ");
        WeightOfPackage = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter how many miles the package will travel: ");
        MilesShipped = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public static void calculations() {
        if (WeightOfPackage <= 1) {
            result = MilesShipped / 1000 * tax;
        } else if (WeightOfPackage > 1 && WeightOfPackage <= 5) {
            result = MilesShipped / 1000 * tax1;
        } else if (WeightOfPackage > 5 && WeightOfPackage <= 10) {
            result = MilesShipped / 1000 * tax2;
        } else if (WeightOfPackage > 10) {
            result = MilesShipped / 1000 * tax3;
        }
    }

    public static void printOutput() {
        System.out.print("Your cost is: " + result);
    }

    public static void displayTable() {

    }
}
```

Output is as below:

[image]

Comment: Still outputs 0.0 for some reason and I'm not sure why? Your code looks good and it should output the correct answer, but it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause I checked it properly. _Enter weight of package in KG: 1
Enter how many miles the package will travel: 2000
Your cost is: 3.4_

Comment: Ya, I just tried it in Eclipse instead of JGrasp and its output is 0.0.

Comment: Never mind, I found my mistake. I had ShippingMiles as an Int and WeightOfPackage as a double and it didn't want to output the answer due to the incompatibilities. Still outputting the wrong answer though, but I'm sure it's just something else I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Strange! I pasted the whole code with the output. Its working fine.

Comment: OK, completely figured it out now! Thanks for everyone's help! I just need to switch around MilesShipped / 1000 to 1000/ MilesShipped and it outputs correctly.